# border issues in css and html

Tags: html, css

I am running into this issue with CSS + HTML. When I click on the image the image is not given the proper border size.

http://jsfiddle.net/kcyDC/1/

I have tried a few things in chrome developer kit, all to no avail.

HTML

```
<div class="btns">
    <input type="radio" name="a" value="a" id="a" />
    <label for="a">
        <img src="http://a1.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Music/a2/6b/7d/mzi.cpbdtjki.100x100-75.jpg"/>
    </label>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.btns input[type="radio"] {
    display: none;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resolve this by setting the label's display to `inline-block`:

```
input[type="radio"] + label {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

so it takes the full height of the contained image.

Updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kcyDC/5/

Comment: Awesome! except that when several are clicked they stays highlighted ! D:

Comment: Are you sure? Works for me, as long as they have the same names (the only way radio buttons will set/unset each other without Javascript involved): http://jsfiddle.net/kcyDC/6/

Answer (score 1):

Paul Robe almost has it, but there remains a gap at the bottom. Putting the border on the image solves that.

```
input[type="radio"] + label {
    display: inline-block;
}
input[type="radio"] + label img { /* this is the null state */
    border: 0px;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label img {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

[NEW Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QV4G4/4/)

To clarify Paul's point about height: a label is an inline element and won't automatically adjust its height to fit its contents. It assumes it should be as high as any text that would go inside it. Changing the display rule makes it more like a lock-level element that *does* adjust its height.

Comment: Just doing the last part should be enough, all he should do is put "img" after label and then he should be good to go :-)

Comment: The pseudo class stays active even after it is unselectd. I have tried an unchecked pseudo class but that fails. Any idea why?

Comment: @user2783087 You need to define a "null" state. See my revised code and new fiddle.